# Definition of "Cross-Dimensional"?

Tags: meaning

From what I understood, it is something related to the word "Cross-Section", which is defined as a surface or shape that intersects with an three dimensional object with a plane.

but I wonder, with this word, is there anything more too it or is it basically the same thing, the word I heard it from is here:
https://mangapark.net/manga/fairy-tail/i1628464/9

Comment: Are you really asking about the word *cross-deimsnional* or about *cross-dimensional*? You can edit your title any time to clarify.

Comment: @ThePhoton, hi, this is the user, I just could not log in from one of my computers and it just made a user, it is referring to the word “Cross-Dimensional”.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is anything to do cross-sections, or "dimensions" in the ordinary, or even the mathematical sense of the word.

*Dimension* has been used in Science Fiction for at least seventy five years to refer to other worlds than our own: not other planets, but whole universes parallel to our own.

I haven't found this meaning in any online dictionaries, but *The Science Fiction Encyclopaedia* says, in its article on "dimension":

> The possible existence of Parallel worlds displaced from ours along a
>   fourth spatial dimension (in the same way that a series of
>   two-dimensional universes might lie next to one another like the
>   pages of a book) is a popular hypothesis in sf, **and such worlds are
>   frequently referred to as "other dimensions"**.  *(Emphasis added)*

I believe that *cross-dimensional* refers to this meaning: "Cross-dimensional magic" is magic that crosses the boundary between some parallel worlds, or dimensions.

Comment: Interesting, I read the story, and it doesn't really refer to any alternate dimensions, it is just a power of destruction. From what I understand, it is just a means of everything caught in the volume of the blast is destroyed.

Comment: I found a website that has the question is referring to, https://www.synonyms.com/synonym/cross-dimensional

Comment: I found that site, and tried to find a definition in it, then gave up and looked elsewhere. The items it lists are emphatically not synonyms  to my understanding: _cross dimensional_ doesn't suggest any of those to me.

Comment: @C.Jordan, your original source is a fantasy comic. They may use the word *cross-dimensional* in the science fiction sense just to give color to the story, without ever explaining it more deeply.

Comment: Okay, thank you, sorry for the trouble, both of you